# How to hook/monitor network calls made by integrated third party libraries?

Tags: android, security, http, networking

We are working on an ad mediation project that requires integrating an arbitrary number of third party libraries into a larger framework. All libraries have the common behavior of contacting an external server and returning a valid Android layout or failing, but we can assume no knowledge or control over their internal functions.

The server interaction carried out by a third-party library is opaque from the standpoint of the framework/app that initiates the call sequence. This potentially allows any library implemented to access and transmit sensitive information based on the permissions of an app.

The objective is for the calling process to be able to capture the http request being made by an integrated library at the framework/app level before it is passed out to the network. Ideal case would be the ability to process and potentially block the request. An alternative would be to find a way to log requests and provide feedback for actionable analysis.

I'm not finding anything helpful in the docs or searching forums. Is this possible in Android?

Comment: Any hint here? I'm facing the same problem 2.5 years after you had it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could think about a second helper-app without permissions, which takes the 3rd-party libs as plugins. Your main-app communicates via AIDL with your helper-app. The 3rd-party libs can only give abstract commands like 'load_ad https://...'. The actual requests are done by your main-app. Alternatively to AIDL the 3rd-party libraries could broadcast their commands (see [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)).

The second app uses the same [android:sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) and creates a permission which can only be granted to your main-app. This way the helper-app is the only possible client of your main-app.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are suggesting. Our framework creates a widget/SDK to wrap multiple widget/SDKs provided by various ad providers. It holds a screen view and calls the third-party SDK wrapper, the SDK does whatever magic it does to produce a view which is pushed to the screen through our widget.

Comment: Also, the 3rd party framework is passed click events so that it can respond correctly. Doing the interaction across AIDL might be possible, but requires casual users to install 2 aps. We want build the framework to better monitor network behavior, preferably without requiring a helper app.

Comment: OK. Then I don't know a solution. I suppose there is no possibility to host the widgets in a secure way if you don't trust them. Intercepting HTTP traffic would mean to intercept at a very low level (Socket?) which every library has to use. But there you don't see HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom URLStreamHandlerFactory and URLStreamHandler and set it from application onCreate() by calling URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(this)
it will allow to capture all network traffic even made by third party library.