# Android (xamarin) block 3rd party module from using http requests

Tags: android, http, xamarin, block

We have a simple xamarin Android app which utilizes the internet connectivity for some stuff.
A 3rd party component we are using is sending data over HTTP in order to enable some additional features which we don't need or use at all.
Since we care about the mobile data traffic consumed and privacy in general - is it possible to block it somehow? To force tunneling all requests and filter accordingly?

Thanks.

Comment: So you have a third party library sending HTTP requests.  Its either one of two things-  those requests are needed for its operation (in which case blocking it is bad) or they aren't, in which case its literally malware. In the second case, the answer is DO NOT USE IT.  In no case is filtering and dropping the requests the right answer.

Comment: Those requests are needed for some extra features which we are not using. The data consumed is problematic for us. Thanks for helping me to clear this out better.

Comment: Your 3rd party component should have some option to disable it. Otherwise I'd follow @Gabe's advice too.

Comment: Obviously it has no API to disable it from communicating and no proper alternatives exist.
It was decided to post here, on stackoverflow, as a last resort. Otherwise we will have to drop major functionality in our app.
Thnx for your attention so far.

Comment: Seems like someone had a similar issue in the past - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488907/how-to-hook-monitor-network-calls-made-by-integrated-third-party-libraries
and here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313231/programmatically-intercept-traffic-originated-by-android-3rd-party-libraries-inc

Comment: @baraka Did you got any solution to this?

Comment: @VinayakBevinakatti sorry mate, not yet.. maybe a bounty is needed here ;)

Comment: @baraka While researching about this I came across Network Security Configuration which is available in Android N which provides some cool stuffs. Worth look into it - https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html

Comment: @VinayakBevinakatti I can't see how we can benefit from that. It relates to CA trusts. Am i wrong?